# Python: nd array to csv

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am a real beginner in Python and trying to make a script that saves Pickled nd arrays into csv files. 
Below is the code I wrote but it is not giving anything when run in terminal.
What do you think is the problem? I am totally clueless...

Thanks a lot. in advance

> input => s01.dat, s02.dat, ..., s32.dat
>
> each .dat file has {'labels' : ((2d array in here)), 'data': ((3d array in here))}

```
import cPickle
import numpy as np

def csv_writer(file_name):
    x = cPickle.load(open(file_name, 'rb'))
    labels = x['labels']
    data = x['data']

    write_path_1 = file_name + '_labels.csv'
    write_path_2 = file_name + '_data.csv'

    np.savetxt(write_path_1, labels, fmt = '%.6f', delimiter=",")

    with file(wirte_path_2, 'w') as datafile:
        datafile.write('#Array shape: {0}\n'.format(data.shape))
        for data_slice in data:
            datafile.write('# New slice in 3dimension\n')
            np.savetxt(datafile, data_slice, fmt = '%.8f', delimiter = ",")


for i in range(1, 10):
    path = 's0' + str(i) + '.dat'
    csv_writer(path)

for i in range(10, 32):
    path = 's' + str(i) + '.dat'
    csv_writer(path)
```

Comment: how do you run it in terminal?

Comment: just:  python xxxx.py

Comment: What are you expecting?  Is it creating the  `csv` files?  I don't expect any screen display since you aren't printing anything.

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify your script in this way. try:

```
import cPickle
import numpy as np

def csv_writer(file_name):
    x = cPickle.load(open(file_name, 'rb'))
    labels = x['labels']
    data = x['data']

    write_path_1 = file_name + '_labels.csv'
    write_path_2 = file_name + '_data.csv'

    np.savetxt(write_path_1, labels, fmt = '%.6f', delimiter=",")

    with file(wirte_path_2, 'w') as datafile:
        datafile.write('#Array shape: {0}\n'.format(data.shape))
        for data_slice in data:
            datafile.write('# New slice in 3dimension\n')
            np.savetxt(datafile, data_slice, fmt = '%.8f', delimiter =     ",")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1, 10):
        path = 's0' + str(i) + '.dat'
        csv_writer(path)

    for i in range(10, 32):
        path = 's' + str(i) + '.dat'
        csv_writer(path)
```

Comment: sorry my answer was on 'non-edited' question. i'll update it

Comment: hmm...still not working but can't thank you more for you help!

Comment: You can use `csv.writer` to handle the CSV build.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be using the csv module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html